# How do I send a form to a URL with an ID route

Tags: html, node.js

So In my nodejs webapp I have this ;

```
    app.post("auth/:token", function(req, res) {
  let str = req.params.token;
  if(str === certToken){
    res.send("SUCCESS");
  }
});
```

and I want to send this HTML form :

```
  <form class="form-signin" action=":token" method="post">
```

yet I always have this error :

```
Cannot POST /auth/example
```

and I'm lost

EDIT :

the HTML file

Please sign in
        
        
          
             Remember me
          
        
        Sign in
        © 2017-2020

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do other routes work fine ?

Comment: Have you try to set `action="/token"` ?

Comment: @Sagar It seems like so

Comment: @MikeGerard doesn't seem to be working either

Comment: Can you put more of your html code ?

Comment: @MikeGerard I've just added the HTML form in my previous post